# How to detect a link within div in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

If someone clicks on a link within a div with the class "foo" I want the list items within this div to show. How can I do this?

Here's my failed attempt:

```
   $('div > li').hide();
   $('div.foo > a').click(function(event) {
       $('div.foo > li').show();
       event.preventDefault();
   });


<ul>
    <div class="foo">
        <a href="#">Animals +</a>
        <li>Cat</li>
        <li>Dog</li>
        <li>Rabbit</li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: For starters, `<div`> isn't a valid child of `<ul>`; only `<li>` is allowed. You might notice that the syntax highlighter is severely confused by your markup...

Comment: This code works: http://jsfiddle.net/Qafy8/ However, I agree with **Matt Ball**, this HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a problem with your html.

It should be something like this,

```
<div class="foo">      
    <a href="#">Animals +</a>
    <ul>
       <li>Cat</li>
       <li>Dog</li>
       <li>Rabbit</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then in jQuery, like this,

```
$('div.foo > ul').hide();
$('div.foo > a').click(function(event) {
   $(this).next('ul').show();
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Ng8/), and try not to forget putting it inside the [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler

<sub>Welcome to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)</sub>
<sub>Don't forget to accept an answer</sub>